# Edit field in background while keeping an Angular UI Modal open

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/10JowHjyKPgej1L6ofq9?p=preview) I have an Angular UI modal that's open and doesn't allow to edit/change anything in background. I need to edit a text field while keeping the modal window open. Is this possible?

HTML

```
Enter 222 in this field without closing the modal:<input type="text" ng-model="someField">

<style>
      .modal-backdrop.in {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      .app-modal .modal-dialog {
          top: 80px;
          width: 180px;
       }
</style>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">

    <div class="modal-header">
        <p class="modal-title">The Title</p>
    </div>

        SOME CONTENT

</script>
```

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('ctl', function ($scope,$uibModal) {

    $scope.modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
        windowClass: 'app-modal',
        backdrop: 'static'
      }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible you must set z-index to the input element. Take a look at this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/MdmsjJuUxZdDHBTQeNet?p=preview

```
input {
        z-index: 100000;
        position: relative;
      }
```

Comment: why do you need `position: relative;` ?

Comment: remove it and see what happed ;) z-index does not work with static positioned elements.

Comment: The problem that I have with your approach is that the field is shown on top of the modal. I need the modal to be on top of the field, and at the same time to be able to enter a value in the field. [Look at this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/yEK0y0MtC5Tnzkia3VDJ?p=preview).